# How to make swagger 3 show multiple responses on swagger UI using annotations?

Tags: java, annotations, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

Is it possible to use the latest swagger 3 release to show in response model not only one response class. I want to show all possible variants (e.g. 3 possible child classes can be in response - not only base class or one of child). I think, there are lots of cases where polymorphic response is returned. I have such case but I can't document it in swagger-UI using java annotations. I tried @ApiModel with subtypes and parent parameterers but this have no effect on UI. I have seen lots of bugs and issues on GitHub about my issue but still have not found any examples how to make it possible.